# Firebase cloud function error: Maximum call size stack size exceeded

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I've made firebase cloud function which adds the claim to a user that he or she has paid (set paid to true for user):

```js
 const admin = require("firebase-admin");
 
 exports.addPaidClaim = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
       // add custom claim (paid)
       return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(data.uid, {
         paid: true,
       }).then(() => {
         return {
           message: `Succes! ${data.email} has paid for the course`,
         };
       }).catch((err) => {
         return err;
       });
     });
```

However, when I'm running this function: I'm receiving the following error: "Unhandled Rejection (RangeError): Maximum call stack size exceeded". I really don't understand why this is happening. Does somebody see what could cause what's getting recalled which in turn causes the function to never end?

Comment: Try replacing `return err;` with `throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', error.message);`

Comment: I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Have you tried deleting and redeploying your function? I don't see anything immediately wrong with what you've written

Comment: I have, but this doesn't make a difference. How do I debug this function in firebase? I'm not getting any feedback on what's causing this large call stack size

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous operations need to return a promise as stated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#:%7E:text=To%20return%20data%20after%20an%20asynchronous%20operation%2C%20return%20a%20promise.%20The%20data%20returned%20by%20the%20promise%20is%20sent%20back%20to%20the%20client.%20For%20example%2C%20you%20could%20return%20sanitized%20text%20that%20the%20callable%20function%20wrote%20to%20the%20Realtime%20Database%3A). Therefore, Cloud Functions is trying to serialize the data contained by promise returned by transaction, then send it in JSON format to the client. I believe your setCustomClaims does not send any object to consider it as an answer to the promise to finish the process so it keeps in a waiting loop that throws the Range Error.

To avoid this error I can think of two different options:

- Add a paid parameter to be able to send a JSON response (and remove the setCustomUserClaim if it there isn’t any need to change the user access control because [they are not designed to store additional data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#best_practices_for_custom_claims)) .
- Insert a promise that resolves and sends any needed information to the client. Something like:

```js
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request({
          url: URL,
          method: "POST",
          json: true,
          body: queryJSON //A json variable I've built previously
        }, function (error, response, body) {
          if (error) {
            reject(error);
          } 
          else {
            resolve(body)
          } 
        });
      });
```

Comment: Okay, but in this case the data is used to store access control. Though this might not be handy in the long run. SHould I use firebase realtime database? 

What should queryjson consist of? setCustomUserClaims?

Comment: You can keep the setCustomClaims(), just add another variable that you can send to complete the promise. Without knowing much about your App it's hard to know if a RDB or a regular datastore would be enough. In the body you need to add the response that is waiting the Client, even just a single String with the confirmation should be enough.